# Run a function after jquery each finishes

Tags: jquery, each

I would like to run a function after a single iteration of a $.each has run. So for example, I am iterating through a list of checked check boxes and grabbing the values from an input field, for each one checked.

I want to change the background of each div, after I have stored the value from the input field.

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('.post-select-checkbox:checked'), function() { 
  var code = jQuery(this).parents('.single').find('.code').text();
});
```

But Id like to achieve something like:

```
    jQuery.each(jQuery('.post-select-checkbox:checked'), function() { 
      var code = jQuery(this).parents('.single').find('.code').text();
    }, function() {
      jQuery(this).css("background", "green");
    });
```

But this doesn't actually run.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a little ass-backwards, but this is how I was able to achieve it.

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('.post-select-checkbox:checked'), function() { 
  var code = jQuery(this).parents('.single').find('.code').text();
  changeBackgroundToGreen();
});

function changeBackgroundToGreen() {
    jQuery.each(jQuery('.post-select-checkbox:checked'), function() {
        jQuery(this).parents('.single').css("background", "#96FF73");
    }); 
}
```

Comment: ... Why can't you just put that one line of code inside the first each?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
jQuery('.post-select-checkbox:checked').each(function() { 
  var code = jQuery(this).parents('.single').find('.code').text();
  jQuery(this).css("background", "green");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery each does not have third argument. Probably you have to do something like this.

```
var arr=jQuery('.post-select-checkbox:checked');
var len=arr.length;
 jQuery.each(, function(index,value) { 
      var code = jQuery(this).parents('.single').find('.code').text();
      if(index==len-1)
           chngeBackground(this)

    });

function changeBackGround(obj)
{
      jQuery(obj).css("background", "green");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am missing the point here... but why can't you just do this?

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('.post-select-checkbox:checked'), function() { 
  var code = jQuery(this).parents('.single').find('.code').text();
  jQuery(this).css("background", "green");
});
```

Comment: @Dirgh what do you mean